# Python - Sorting dict using tuple keys

Tags: python, sorting, key, tuples

My question is related to the answer of this one:
[Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

> And for those wishing to sort on keys instead of values:
>
> ```
> import operator
> x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
> sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
> ```

How do I sort on keys like above when my keys are tuples? For example, `A:  {(-2929109664628200379, 10): table, (-3884855813103006483, 15): chair}`, sorting using the second number from the key.

**Edit**
Made it by creating a function `getKey` to return the value I wanted, now I realize it was a trivial question, thank you @jonrsharpe

Comment: There are dozens of questions on sorting with `key`; all you need is a function that maps the input (in this case, a tuple `((keypart1, keypart2), value)`) to the thing you want to sort on (`keypart2`). This is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the keys and do a lookup, sorting the keys by the second element:

```
d = {(-2929109664628200379, 10): "table", (-3884855813103006483, 15): "chair"}

sted = [(k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d,key=itemgetter(1))]
```